# Rails how to loop and build one object based on multiple queries to the same table?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

```
@companies = this has lets say 3 but is dynamic in range


@companies.each do |c|
  workers = current_user.workers.find_by_company_id(c.id)
end
```

At the end of all this I want workers to be like it was the result of one query. But in this case the object needs to be the combination of the 3 queries.

Possible?

Answer (score 3):

This?

```
 workers = current_user.workers.where(:company_id => @companies.map(&:id))
```

Comment: That's right I forgot about map. Thanks. I love elegant answers like this.

Answer (score 1):

Rails maps the id's automatically for you:

```
current_user.workers.find_all_by_company_id(@companies)
```